# How to reload tableview's data after JSON data has downloaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I call the `getPrizesData` in `func viewDidLoad()`

I call `reload` after finishing download the JSON data.

But it didn't refresh my cells in the tableview,

How to fix it ? Thanks

```
@IBOutlet var invoice: UITableView!

func getPrizesData()-> Void{
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3002/invoices.json")
    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask =
    sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(url,
        completionHandler: {(location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!)->Void in
            if (error == nil){
                let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
                if let prizes = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject, options: .MutableLeaves, error: nil) as? NSArray {
                    let prizesDictionary = prizes[0] as NSDictionary
                    let toPrizesArray = prizesDictionary["to_prizes"] as NSArray
                    self.items = toPrizesArray as [AnyObject] as [String]
                    self.invoice.reloadData()
                }
                else {
                    println("error")
                }
            }else{

                println(error)
            }

    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data is downloaded on non-main thread. UI must be updated only from main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.invoice.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`downloadTaskWithURL` method calls its completion handler on the background thread. All UI updates (such as reloading tableView data) have to be performed on the main thread. You can use GCD to update your tableView on the main thread when your data is ready. E.g.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      self.invoice.reloadData()
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 update**
You can update the UI only on the main queue

1.For getting a main queue asynchronously

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {                                        
    //code for updating the UI 
 }
```

2.For getting a main queue synchronously

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync{                                         
//code for updating the UI 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update ui on the main thread, so use the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.invoice.reloadData()
}
```

Note: works with swift 5